# Rails and Devise Missing link to host

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-5, spree-auth-devise

I am very confused with how to provide the default_url_options. I am getting this error

```
Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
```

I am using spreecommerce which uses devise for authentication. This error is occurring durring password reset on my development environment. I have not tested it in a production environment yet. 
I am using this in my environments/development

```
config.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:3000' }
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost:3000'
```

in my rails console when I do `Rails.application.routes.default_url_options` I get `{:host => Rails.application.config.domain}`. The same thing happends when I do `Rails.applicaiton.default_url_options`

None of the solutions I have found have worked.

Comment: I stuck with the same issue. Couple days ago adding default_url_options solved my problem, but not now.

Comment: It works for me on a different computer. I have no idea why it is broken.

Comment: Here is what I can see:
my option variable (host is nil)

`{:controller=>"spree/user_confirmations", :action=>"create", :host=>nil, :port=>3000, :confirmation_token=>2904397, :path=>"/user/spree_user/confirmation", :script_name=>"/", :params=>{:confirmation_token=>2904397}, :user=>nil, :password=>nil}`

and

`>> Rails.application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options`
`=> {:host=>"localhost", :port=>3000}`


but `Rails.application.action_mailer.default_url_options` is empty

Comment: `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 } `helped me

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** In my case Spree::Store.current vanished - I had to recreate it.

---

I tried set `default_url_options` for routes and into environments. But with no luck.

So I got into `spree_auth_devise-3.1.0` gem source code:

```
@confirmation_url = spree.spree_user_confirmation_url(:confirmation_token => token, :host => Spree::Store.current.url)
```

So for the host, it's using Spree::Store. Then I went into console and got that my Spree::Store.current is empty:

```
(byebug) Spree::Store.current.url
nil
```

So simply creating a store with dummy data resolved my problem.

```
store = Spree::Store.new
store.name = 'test'
store.url = 'http://localhost:3000'
store.code = 'spree'
store.default = true
store.save
```